# Rails precompile assets does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

Hello im migrating to production server and im getting this error (i enabled error reporting)

```
bootstrap.css isn't precompiled
```

so i run

```
rvmsudo rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production
```

and error output is

```
rake aborted!
Unexpected character '#' (line: 12521, col: 0, pos: 350962)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:2357:10736)
    at js_error (<eval>:2357:10955)
    at parse_error (<eval>:2357:12489)
    at Object.next_token [as input] (<eval>:2357:17217)
    at next (<eval>:2357:18479)
    at semicolon (<eval>:2357:19324)
    at simple_statement (<eval>:2357:21849)
    at <eval>:2357:20245
    at <eval>:2357:19536
    at <eval>:2357:31209
    at Object.parse (<eval>:2357:31418)
  (in /var/www/default/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
```

application.js contains

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

what now ?

Can i turn it OFF ? I really need to run that app :p

EDIT: I FOUND what .js file is doing that error.. its
**assets/admin/admin.js**

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

If i remove

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

nothing happen, but if i remove that file its working.. (every change i need restart server and i set compiling on the fly)

Comment: just try "rake assets:precompile" without the rest - it might give an error, but see what it is

Comment: hello, it return same output

Comment: You have an error in one of js files. It should show up in log in development as well.

Comment: you are right, but production.log ends by `Compiled application.js` and development.log ends by `Compiled bootstrap.css` no errors there

Comment: im using 2 bootstraps, one for frontend (themed) and one for backend

Comment: if i remove bootstrap.css the errror is same im getting crazy !